# Powers of roots satisfying irreducible polynomials form a basis for extension field

Tags: vector-spaces, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

> For a polynomial $p(x)$ of degree $n$, irreducible in some field $F$, and if $a$ is some root of $p$ in an extension field, then $\{1, a, a^2, a^3 ... a^{n-1} \}$ are linearly independent.

I came across [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/709682/for-an-irreducible-polynomial-p-and-root-alpha-f-alphaf-degree-of) which assumes a linear combination of basis, then I would be able to produce you another polynomial $w$ of degree $n$ such that $w(a)$ is a root. This implies that $\gcd(p, w)=(x-a)$, and the author claims it contradicts the irreducibility of $p$.

I don't see how it contradicts the irreducibility of $p$, though. Because doesn't irreducibility just mean that you aren't able to factor the polynomial in the field? However, the factor that that $p $ and $w$ have in common is $(x-a)$, and the factoring is done in the extension field, isn't it, since $a$ is an element of the extended field?

We haven't done a lot on abstract algebra, so apologies if this is a basic misconception.

Comment: F[x] is an euclidean domain, and the gcd is still in F[x]. That statement just say the gcd cannot be 1. I think the implied is (x-a)|gcd(p,w)

Comment: Does this imply that $gcd(p, w)$ is not actually $x-a$, but there exists some other element in $F[x]$ being the gcd? After all $x-a$ is not in $F[x]$ right?

Comment: Basically, because the gcd cannot be outside of F[x].

Comment: Is there a theorem for this? That if 2 polynomials have a root, even in the extended field, their gcd in F[x] is not trivial?

Comment: It's simply because the gcd is the same as the generator of the ideal. So if $x-a$ divides both, then it must divide the gcd.

Comment: I see, wow, that's a clever way to think about it! So I don't know what the gcd is, I just know it has to be in F[x] and it must divide x-a? But then I have another question, for x-a to divide gcd(p,w), it would mean f(x)(x-a)=gcd right? Wouldn't that now mean f(x) is not in F[x]?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103832/discussion-between-david-cheng-and-yip-jung-hon).